# Is implementing a javascript class in multiple files like this good practice?

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm currently handling a huge project which contains class implementations of more than 8000 lines.

I don't want to create subclasses to group functions because it makes a namespace mess.

What I've thought about is having a file with the class declaration in which I declare all the methods inside the class, and then in different files have these methods implemented and exported. In the implementation file, the method takes an extra parameter, `_this`, which is a reference to the class instance, and is used to access the class' members and methods.

Example: *mybigclass.js*:

```
import {
 add2,
 add3
} from './adders.js'

class MyBigClass{
  constructor(){
    this.somevalue=0;
  }
  add2(){
    add2(this);
  }
  add3(){
    add3(this);
  }
}
```

And in *adders.js*:

```
function add2(_this){
  _this.somevalue+=2;
}
function add3(_this){
  _this.somevalue+=3;
}

export {add2, add3}
```

I'm not an expert in javascript, so I'd like to know exactly how terrible this is. Would it be flooding the stack with unnecessary function frames? Would it add much overhead? What alternatives are there?

**Note:** The code example is just an example, the class methods I'm using actually `belong` in the same class and are not redundant.

I'm using `webpack` to bundle it all together.

Comment: @zx485 It's a webapp, i'd say it IS as complex as photoshop. Multiple draggable windows with co-related graphics and tables, synchronized cursors, measurements over the graphics, etc.

Comment: I think by architecture design it's a common practice to do in the first place, What you're trying to do is called "centralizing" or "Single source of truth". Usually in js we don't directly pass `this` as a an argument to a function, rather than using `.call(this, arg...)` or `.apply(this, [arg])`. to keep `this` context. One more thing, you can google keyword "factory pattern design", it should be useful your your case

Comment: @DucHong Thank you. Then in the "header" file, I'd have this same "interface" functions but using `funcname.call(this,arg..)` instad of calling them with `this` as an argument?

Comment: actually, using `.call(this)` or `.bind(this)` or `.apply(this)` takes a bit of practice and some with pain to get the concept, if you know what I meant. In the "root" file, where all the child functions will inherit from, you dont need to do pass `this`, just think of it as the most generic handler for all the context it will be called from. In my opinion, this work requires a bit of hand-on experience with js and as you said you dont have much experience, try to experiment with a small scale and see how far you can go

Comment: @DucHong `bind()` is discarded since it creates a new function, meaning I'd have new function objects for each instance, which is not ideal. The alternative would be using call or apply from the "interface" function apparently.

Comment: well, you need to have a deeper look into the differences between those three. In short, `.bind` wont execute your function immediately until it's needed, usually it's suitable for event handler like click, hover etc. Meanwhile `.call` and `.apply` will execute immediately, no wonder knowing where and when to use takes a bit of practice as I said in the previous comment.